# How do I add dijit layout panes to a custom templated widget? - (Dojo 1.10)

Tags: dojo

I'm not clear how to include the layout modules for creating content panes in dojo.  I want to layout some content inside one of my widgets.

In the dojo tookit [example](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/layout.html) they have a require these modules

```
require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane"]);
```

But the widget where I want to include this is like this

```
 define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/parser",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
    "dojo/text!./home/templates/HomePage.html",
    "xstyle/css!./home/css/HomePage.css",
    "dijit/layout/LayoutContainer",
    "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane"
], function (
    declare,
    parser,
    _WidgetBase,
    _TemplatedMixin,
     _WidgetsInTemplateMixin,
    template,
    css,
    lc,
    bc,
    cp
) {

    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {

        templateString: template,

        postCreate: function () {
            this.inherited(arguments);

        },

        startup: function () {
            this.inherited(arguments);

        }
    });
});
```

And the widget HTML is like this

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top'">Top pane</div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'leading'">Leading pane</div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'">Center pane</div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'trailing'">Trailing pane</div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'bottom'">Bottom pane</div>
    </div>

 </div>
```

But it doesn't work, even though I included these dependencies

```
"dijit/layout/LayoutContainer",
"dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
"dijit/layout/ContentPane"
```

Where to put the required modules in order to use the layout widgets inside my custom template widget?  Or am I missing something else?

**EDIT:**  I was able to make it work using this code by placing the require above the define

```
require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer"]);
require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/ready"], function (parser, ready) {
    ready(function () {
        parser.parse();
    });
});
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
    "dojo/text!./home/templates/HomePage.html",
    "xstyle/css!./home/css/HomePage.css",
    "./home/HomeNavigationWidget"
], function (
    declare,
    _WidgetBase,
    _TemplatedMixin,
     _WidgetsInTemplateMixin,
    template,
    css,
    HomeNavigationWidget

) {

    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin], {

        templateString: template

    });
});
```

**EDIT:**  I found that the reason the layout worked after was because of [_WidgetsInTemplateMixin](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin.html).  Adding this allowed for the layout widgets to be used inside the template. And I removed the two require statements above the define and it worked fine.  In the dojoConfig, parseOnLoad is set to false.

Answer (score 2):

From your example it looks like you are trying to add the layout panes to the template of your custom widget (`Editor.html`).

If this is the case, then you can just require the modules in the widget file like this:

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_WidgetBase",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dojomat/_AppAware",
    "../_global/widget/NavigationWidget",
    "dojo/text!./templates/Editor.html",
    "dojo/text!./css/Editor.css",
    "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", 
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane"
], function (
     declare,
     _WidgetBase,
     _TemplatedMixin,
     _AppAware,
     NavigationWidget,
     template,
     css
) {
    return declare([_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _AppAware], {
       // widget code
    });
});
```

Note how you didn't have to also declare them as parameters in the function passed into `define` since they are not used in the code - they are just listed in the array of dependencies so you will be sure they are loaded when the template is generated.

Also, notice how the `dojo/parse` module is no longer required - this is because in the example, the code was parsed in the `index.html` page automatically, using a dojo config option (`parseOnLoad`). However, in your code, I expect you already have a way to parse the code which is defined in the main entry point of your application.

Comment: I did try your suggestion, see my original edited post above. For some reason it wouldn't work for me. Until after I added the _WidgetsInTemplateMixin.